Método sem retorno
estou desenvolvendo uma API de gerenciamento de tarefas em Java, utilizando o Spring Framework e estou passando por um grande problema, meu método de atualização de tarefas me retorna apenas o código HTTP 403, mesmo com o usuário logado (não estou trabalhando com roles) e o console me retorna apenas a query que foi feita quando eu chamo o método:
Hibernate: 
select
    u1_0.usuario_id,
    u1_0.login,
    u1_0.senha 
from
    usuario u1_0 
where
    u1_0.login=?

Ele não retorna nada além disso, nem uma exception. E além de não retornar nada diferente dessa query, também não consigo debugar, pois quando tento, também nada acontece! Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema? Segue aqui o meu código para atualização de tarefas:
@PostMapping("/atualizar_tarefa")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<TarefaResponseDTO> atualizaTarefa(@RequestBody AtualizaTarefaDTO dados){

    Usuario usuario = ts.buscaUsuarioLogado();

    Tarefas tarefa = ts.buscaTarefa(dados.id());

    tarefa.setNome(dados.nome());
    tarefa.setDescricao(dados.descricao());
    Tarefas tarefaSalva = tr.save(tarefa);

    TarefaResponseDTO dto = new TarefaResponseDTO(tarefaSalva, usuario.getUsuario_id());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(dto);
}

Gostaria de enfatizar que os métodos: buscaUsuarioLogado e buscaTarefa estão presentes e funcionando em outros métodos. Agradeço a disposição de qualquer um que possa me ajudar.
